# How does Mac do case-insensitive file names and paths?

Tags: macos

I am implementing a function to check if two file names can coexist in a folder on Mac.
This seemed easy until I hit issue with "ß" and "SS". while files with those two names can exist in the same folder, various NSString comparing methods all consider them as the same. I've tried caseInsensitiveCompare, localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare, compare with NSCaseInsensitiveSearch and systemLocale and none of them work. Anyone knows how the OS do case insensitive check?

Answer (score 0):

The duplicate file name check is dependent on the OS's file system, so you should use an instance of `NSFileManager` to determine file name equality.

```
//Your string to check if it exists. Obviously, it should not be nil
NSString * filePath = nil;

//NSFileManager assumes tilde's are already resolved. 
filePath = [filePath stringByExpandingTildeInPath];

NSFileManager * fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
{
   //A file already exists with that name. 
}
```